# Canvas cant find image files

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to load an image with loadImage function of canvas with a path, but it doesn't find it and i don't know why because it is supposed to loadImage only if the path exists.

> Err : `Error: ENOENT, No such file or directory 'C:/Users/elpepito11/OneDrive/Bureau/Topaz/base de données/serveurs/1066636825604657183/welcome/welcomeimage/welcomeimage.jpg'

Code :

```js
if(fs.existsSync(imagepath)){
  const { createCanvas, loadImage } = require('canvas');
  const canvas = createCanvas(1920, 1080);
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  const background = await loadImage(imagepath);        
}
```

imagepath :

```js
const serverpath = path.join(__dirname, '..','..','..', "base de données",'serveurs',interaction.guild.id)
const dossierimage = path.join(serverpath, 'welcome', 'welcomeimage')
const imagepath = path.join(dossierimage, 'welcomeimage.jpg')
```

I was excepting it to find the file.

Comment: As this is on your local filesystem is is rather difficult fort us to help you test. I am assuming that you are using `NodeJS` and not attempting to access this through a browser. Have you tried `console.log(imagepath)` to ensure that it is resolving to the location you are expecting?

Comment: @El_3mperor please edit your code in format view.